# How to download a JAR from Github Package Registry for a specific Release version

Tags: github-actions, github-package-registry

**Goal**

I want to have two repositories:

- Repository A: Publishes a JAR to Github Registry
- Repository B: Downloads the JAR from A and publishes a Docker Image containing the JAR.

---

I.e. I'm searching for an API which looks like:

```
wget https://github.com/repoOwner/repoName/packages/1.2.3/my.jar
```

**Question**

Is there a Github Action or API which allows me to download an artifact **from a Github Package Registry** for a specific version?

**Problem**

I know there is a [Github API for the artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#artifacts) but I don't see how I can request the artifact URL **for a specific version**.

Comment: The artifact URL is `https://github.com/<user/org>/<repo>/releases/download/<release>/<filename>` - e.g. https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/releases/download/v0.3.1/dist-v0.3.1.tar.gz

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the super-fast response. The artifacts (JAR, Docker-Image, ...) I publish into the Github Package Registry is not listed as `asset` below the Release, there is only `Source code (zip)` and `Source code (tar.gz)`. I guess I could add `actions/upload-release-asset@v1` with my JAR to my Publish-JAR Workflow. Thanks for that tip!

Comment: If you look at the artifact links from GPR I'd guess they have a predictable structure too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unfortunately not really. The URL contains a HASH. But I could live with the solution mentioned above I guess. Just thought there is a Github Action for retrieving Artifacts of a specific version from the GPR which I just don't see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To **Download the JAR** from the **Github Package Registry** use this URL:

```
https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPO/PACKAGE/VERSION/ARTIFACT.jar
```

- Authenticate with your personal developer token and account name

  - For public repositories the token does not need special permissions
  - For private repositories the token only needs `package:read` permission
- Replace `OWNER` with the Github account name of the repository
  owner
- Replace `REPO` with the repository name
- Replace `PACKAGE` with the group id you published
- Replace `VERSION` with the artifact version you published
- Replace `ARTIFACT` with the artifact id you published

E.g. for [this](https://github.com/abrensch/brouter/packages/118852) Package, were only a `pom` file is published:

```
https://maven.pkg.github.com/abrensch/brouter/org/btools/brouter/1.6.1/brouter-1.6.1.pom
```

Comment: I found this link structure only by accident while receiving an error during `gradle publish`: `could not write to resource *URL*`, not in the documentation.

Comment: Does it still work for anybody else? I get "ERROR 404: Not Found"

Comment: @heringer Yes. I tested the link posted above (public repo) to the `pom` file in the browser and used a Github account and a Personal Access Token. If you want to download from a private repository your account needs to have `package:read` permissions and access to that repo as explained above.

Comment: Thanks, @hb0, I confirmed that. I don't know what I did wrong previously.

Comment: Wanted to build a pipeline where I build env everyday from snapshot. But I cannot figure out how to download lates snapshot jar. Tried url with version, exact name of the jar with timestamp etc. Nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

@hb0 answer is great and helped me a lot.

I will just add my experience, maybe it can help someone else.

I was trying to download the jar file with this command:

```
curl -O --header "Authorization: Bearer $MYSECRETTOKEN" https://maven.pkg.github.com/myorg/myrepo/com/org/mypackage/1.0.0/mypackage-1.0.0.jar
```

But it was returning:

`Moved Permanently`

Then I had to change the command to:

```
curl -O -L https://_:$MYSECRETTOKEN@maven.pkg.github.com/myorg/myrepo/com/org/mypackage/1.0.0/mypackage-1.0.0.jar
```

where `$MYSECRETTOKEN` is an environment var with github token as you probably guessed.